# Laravel socialiteproviders/vkontakte - Driver [vkontakte] not supported

Tags: php, laravel

Это сделал:

`composer require socialiteproviders/vkontakte`

Так выглядит мой `EventServiceProvider` класс:

```php
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        'SocialiteProviders\\VKontakte\\VKontakteExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],
];
```

Вроде бы у меня всё сделано правильно, но выдаёт ошибку:

> Driver [vkontakte] not supported

Comment: Где выдаёт ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, Есть 2 варианта -
Если будешь использовать то что официально дает документация то не сможешь сделать вход через сайты которых нет в их списке.
А если вам нужно сделать вход через различные сайты которых нет в официальной документации то нужно вместо официального пакета Laravel/socialite использовать
<<socialiteproviders/Сайт через который будет сделан вход >>
Вот сайт где есть документация и всё что нужно в связи с этим  https://socialiteproviders.com/
НО НУЖНО ПОМНИТЬ ЧТО ЕСЛИ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕМ ЭТОТ ВАРИАНТ ТО В app.php в массиве providers ИМЕТЬ ТОЛЬКО ТО ЧТО ДАЕТ НАМ ЭТА ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЯ ТО ЕСТЬ ЭТО --> \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
А ТО ЧТО В ОФИЦИАЛЬНОЙ НЕ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ.